# App Service Certificate Error: The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I'm making Azure App Service Certificate and trying to import the certificate to key vault.
But when creating and selecting the key vault from the App service certificate, I got an error:

The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value.

Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Key Vault is set to use "Azure role-based access control" under "Access configuration". It needs to be set to "Vault access policy" instead.

[image]

Currently, App Service Certificate supports only Key Vault access policies, not the RBAC model. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#store-certificate-in-azure-key-vault

Comment: Worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I soloved this problem.
I had used Resource Group name using Japanese characters and then got an error.
I created new Resource Group named with alphabets and underscore. Then tried again, and succeeded.

Comment: I think your answer doesn't make any sense. According to your opinion, will the resource group with Japanese character names have this problem?